# Send two different attachment from two different query's in mail from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to attach two different files from two different queries; this is my code which are causing the error mentioned in the title of this question:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
     @profile_name='MyTestMail
     @body = @body,
     @body_format ='HTML',
     @recipients = 'xyz@zyx.com',
     @subject = @SBJ,
     @importance = HIGH,
     @sensitivity= Confidential,
     @query = 'Select * from XXXXXXXX;',
     @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
     @query_attachment_filename = 'X1.csv',
     @query_result_separator=',',
     @query_result_width =32767,
     @query_result_no_padding=1,
     @query = 'Select * from XXXXXXXX2;',
     @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
     @query_attachment_filename = 'X2.csv',
     @query_result_separator=',',
     @query_result_width =32767,
     @query_result_no_padding=1;
```

I Can successfully send one file as attachment from same code if not repeat query for XXXXXXXX2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to figure out how to send multiple file attachments with sp\_send\_dbmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518261/trying-to-figure-out-how-to-send-multiple-file-attachments-with-sp-send-dbmail)

Comment: @Matsnow I am sorry to disappointing you, but i am looking for something else here, I want to send two files as attachment from two different query's in single email without saving it on local computer.

Comment: @DHARMENDRA SINGH Were you able to find a solution? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Multiple files can be attached only when they are attached from the file system. 
Please refer the below Syntax -

```
 sp_send_dbmail [ [ @profile_name = ] 'profile_name' ]  
        [ , [ @recipients = ] 'recipients [ ; ...n ]' ]  
        [ , [ @copy_recipients = ] 'copy_recipient [ ; ...n ]' ]  
        [ , [ @blind_copy_recipients = ] 'blind_copy_recipient [ ; ...n ]' ]  
        [ , [ @from_address = ] 'from_address' ]  
        [ , [ @reply_to = ] 'reply_to' ]   
        [ , [ @subject = ] 'subject' ]   
        [ , [ @body = ] 'body' ]   
        [ , [ @body_format = ] 'body_format' ]  
        [ , [ @importance = ] 'importance' ]  
        [ , [ @sensitivity = ] 'sensitivity' ]  
        [ , [ @file_attachments = ] 'attachment [ ; ...n ]' ]  
        [ , [ @query = ] 'query' ]  
        [ , [ @execute_query_database = ] 'execute_query_database' ]  
        [ , [ @attach_query_result_as_file = ] attach_query_result_as_file ]  
        [ , [ @query_attachment_filename = ] query_attachment_filename ]  
        [ , [ @query_result_header = ] query_result_header ]  
        [ , [ @query_result_width = ] query_result_width ]  
        [ , [ @query_result_separator = ] 'query_result_separator' ]  
        [ , [ @exclude_query_output = ] exclude_query_output ]  
        [ , [ @append_query_error = ] append_query_error ]  
        [ , [ @query_no_truncate = ] query_no_truncate ]   
        [ , [ @query_result_no_padding = ] @query_result_no_padding ]   
        [ , [ @mailitem_id = ] mailitem_id ] [ OUTPUT ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously running `@attach_query_result_as_file = 1` twice doesn't work. If you cannot send the attachments from the file system, then the only work-around I can think of is to display the first query result in html format in the email body and then only the 2nd query result as attachment using `@attach_query_result_as_file`. I used this strategy to send daily email report.

[image]